# How to remove part of a url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have looked at a good few similar questions on stack overflow but what I have tried doesn't seem to work.

'quotes' is a subfolder with a wordpress installation in it. So, the main root has a wordpress site in it and the 'quotes' subfolder also has a wordpress installation in it.

I have a path something like

```
https://example.com/quotes/uk/travel-packages
https://example.com/quotes/us/travel-packages
```

But I don't want 'quotes' to be in the url, it should just be

```
https://example.com/uk/travel-packages
```

I currently have this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]

    
RewriteRule ^quotes/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

RewriteRule ^uk/(.*) /quotes/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^us/(.*) /quotes/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:** I was trying this on my localhost hence the rewrite base being /example/ so I understand the confusion there now.

Here is the live server .htaccess file for both the root directory and the quotes subfolder in the root directory.

**ROOT:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**QUOTES SUBDIRECTORY**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quotes/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /quotes/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Have you removed `/quotes` from your internal links/URLs?

Comment: The `RewriteBase /example/` does not really make sense in there...

Comment: ...and that `RewriteBase` perhaps suggests the first `RewriteRule` is incorrect (although not that it make a perceivable difference). You should also clarify what you mean exactly by "doesn't seem to work"? From your code it probably isn't doing anything, but it could also result in a redirect loop depending on the underlying filestructure (and requested URLs).

Comment: @MrWhite, I am typing directly into the browser url bar https://example.com/uk/travel-packages and get a 404 error. But if I type https://example.com/quotes/uk/travel-packages then I see the page. I want to be able to access the page without /quotes/ in the url

Comment: @arkascha, that is by default what WordPress gives you for your root installation. The quotes url is representing the folder called quotes in the root folder. It is a second wordpress installation

Comment: "that is by default what WordPress gives you for your root installation" - this looks more suited to a "subdirectory installation"? Although strictly incorrect either way. I assume the reference to "example", should be "quotes" (as stated in the other directives) - otherwise it does not appear to make sense (as arkascha pointed out)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `/quotes` is a subdirectory that contains the WordPress installation and you have already removed `/quotes` from the URL in WordPress itself then you need to configure two `.htaccess` files:

1. One in the document root that internally rewrites (unconditionally) all requests to the `/quotes` subdirectory.
2. And another `.htaccess` file in the `/quotes` subdirectory that routes the request to WordPress - containing the "standard" WordPress front-controller.

In the (root) `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite all requests to WordPress subdirectory
RewriteRule ^ quotes%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

In the `/quotes/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# OPTIONAL...
# Redirect any direct requests for "/quotes/<anything>" back to root
# NB: WP itself *must* already be correctly configured to omit "/quotes" from the URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure only direct requests are redirected and not rewritten requests by the WP front-controller - which would otherwise cause a redirect loop.

---

Alternatively, you have just a single `.htaccess` file in the document root (and remove the `.htaccess` file in the `/quotes` - WordPress - subdirectory). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /quotes

# OPTIONAL...
# Redirect any direct requests for "/quotes/<anything>" back to root
# NB: WP itself *must* already be correctly configured to omit "/quotes" from the URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^quotes/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress front-controller
RewriteRule ^quotes/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

---

It seems from your question update that you also have a 2nd WordPress installation in the document root. It's not possible to have two separate WordPress installations and make them appear as a single WP site in the document root (ie. without specifying the subdirectory as part of the URL) unless there is some discernable difference in the URL structure between the two sites. Otherwise, you don't know which URLs should be routed to the WP installation in the subdirectory and which to the site in the document root.

> Any with `/us` or `/uk` or any country extension in future should go to `/quotes` otherwise it should go to the route or whatever page is being called from the root site like for instance, `https://example.com/contant-us` should go to the root contact us page.

Yes, this is possible. For "any" country extension I assume a string of 2 lowercase letters a-z. Although this does mean that the WP site in the document root cannot have any URLs that start with a 2 letter path segment.

Ordinarily, you would modify the existing directives (as above). However, since this is WordPress, the directives in the `# BEGIN WordPress` code block should not be modified (unless you prevent WP from modifying this). Instead, we will just add some directives *before* the WP front-controller.

In the (root) `/.htaccess` file:

```
# Rewrite any URLs that contain a language code prefix to the subdirectory
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/ quotes%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (Remainder of existing .htaccess file goes here)
```

In the `/quotes/.htaccess` file:

```
# OPTIONAL...
# Redirect any direct requests for "/quotes/<anything>" back to root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (Remainder of existing .htaccess file goes here)
```

This assumes you will be accessing your static resources directly. eg. Using the `/quotes` subdirectory for resources that are contained within this site, so the `/quotes` subdirectory is not entirely hidden.

---

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64589972/369434) to [part two of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589051/wordpress-site-missing-images-after-htaccess-change) with regards to missing static resources (images, CSS and JS) for the second WordPress installation in the subdirectory that could result from implementing the above rewrites/redirects.

- [wordpress site missing images after htaccess change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589051/wordpress-site-missing-images-after-htaccess-change)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I have updated my question to address the issue of the /example I had. I don't understand what you mean by `# NB: WP itself *must* already be correctly configured to omit "/quotes" from the URL`. Would you be able to please clarify that?

Comment: In other words, the internal links that WP generates must already have the `/quotes` part of the URL removed.

Comment: However, I've noticed in your updated question that you have two WordPress installations: one in the root and one in the `/quotes` subdirectory. In this case, it's _impossible_ to "hide" the `/quotes` subdirectory from the requested URL using `.htaccess` because in `.htaccess` it's not possible to know which URLs should be handled by the WP installation in the root and which should be handled by the WP installation in the `/quotes` subdirectory, UNLESS there is a specific pattern to the URLs (eg. they have a `/quotes` prefix!).

Comment: You can't make 2 WP installations look like 1 WP installation (which is what it looks like you are trying to do), unless there is something in the URL-path that differentiates the two installations.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Okay, so if it is not possible to have 2 installations look like 1 which is exactly what I am trying to do, what would the alternative be? Would it not be possible to base it on the `/us/` or `/uk/` part of the url instead of /`quotes`? Because it would be `example.com/us/travel-packages` or `example.com/uk/travel-packages`

Comment: Yes, providing there is some discernable difference between the two URLs for the two different WP sites. So, from your example, which URL(s) should go to the `/quotes` installation and which to the one in the root? Should URLs that start `/us` and `/uk` go to the `/quotes` installation and everything else to root?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Any with `/us` or `/uk` or any country extension in future should go to `/quotes` otherwise it should go to the route or whatever page is being called from the root site like for instance, `https://example.com/contant-us` should go to the root contact us page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the two WP installs and rewriting all requests that contain a 2 letter country code to the WP install in the subdirectory. All other requests go to the WP install in the document root.

Comment: Hi again, since this was getting too long I just asked another question. After shutting down computer and starting it up again and checking the site I noticed that all the assets are missing! If you have time to take a look, the new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589051/wordpress-site-missing-images-after-htaccess-change