# wordpress site missing images after htaccess change

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress installation in the root and another one in a subfolder within the root.

What would normally happen is that the url would look like:

```
https://example.com/quotes/us/some-url
```

but I wanted to remove 'quotes' from the url so it just ended up like:

```
https://example.com/us/some-url
```

Thanks to another stack overflow user, I was able to get that to work with the below htaccess code but I didn't realise that the images are now not showing and I get a 404 error for all of them. This is the root .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/ quotes%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.3.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and the subfolder 'quotes' .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /quotes/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /quotes/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What URL are you using to reference your images in your HTML source? Are the CSS and JS files loading OK?

Comment: Hmm, no. It doesn't seem to be getting the js or css either. The calls to the js and css files are done in the WordPress way ie: enqueue in the functions.php file (in the subdirectory) installation. If I take a look in my browser console, I get a 404 error to this path `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_quotes/style.css?ver=1.0.0`. So, it is looking in the root installation where that theme doesn't exist as it only exists in the subdirectory installation. `wp_enqueue_script('scripts.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts', [], '2', true);`

Comment: @MrWhite, actually just noticed something interesting as well. When I look at an image path it actually shows correctly but the image is not showing. When I go to the image url I get a 404 page not found. So, the image url looks like this: `https://example.com/quotes/wp-content/themes/theme_quotes/assets/images/example_logo.svg` but it redirects to: `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_quotes/assets/images/eaxmple_logo.svg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get a 404 error to this path `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_quotes/style.css?ver=1.0.0`. So, it is looking in the root installation where that theme doesn't exist as it only exists in the subdirectory installation

Currently, we only rewrite requests to the `/quotes` subdirectory when the URL-path starts with a 2-letter language code, since that is the only thing that appears to differentiate the URLs between the two WordPress installs. However, that means that URLs to your static resources (as above) that do not have the language code prefix (and do not reference the `/quotes` subdirectory directly) are not being rewritten and so fail with a 404.

This could perhaps be fixed in WordPress, by including `/quotes` in the URL to your static resources. But that does expose the `/quotes` subdirectory for anybody looking at your HTML source. We would also need to modify the redirect directive in the `/quotes/.htaccess` file to prevent these requests being redirected back to root. **EDIT:** Actually, it looks like this is happening with your images already which already include the full ("correct") URL-path.

What we could do... **in the root `.htaccess` file**, rewrite any request for a static resource (image, CSS or JS file) to the `/quotes` subdirectory if it doesn't exist in the root. For example:

```
# Rewrite any URLs that contain a language code prefix to the subdirectory
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/ quotes%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Rewrite any request for a static resource that does not exist (in the root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|webp|gif)$ quotes%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (Remainder of existing .htaccess file goes here)
```

This does mean that should you have two static resources with the same name (same base URL-path) in both installations then the one in the root installation will "win".

Note that this is a "blind" rewrite... if a particular static resource does not exist in either installation then you will always get the 404 in the `/quotes` installation. But there's no way to really resolve that since there is an element of ambiguity in the URL-path structure.

AND, **in the `/quotes/.htaccess` file**, prevent any direct requests for static resources being redirected back to the root. For example:

```
# Redirect any direct requests for "/quotes/<anything>" back to root
# Except for static resources
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|webp|gif)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# : (Remainder of existing .htaccess file goes here)
```

I'm assuming all your file extensions (to static resources) are lowercase.

You will need to clear your browser cache, since the image redirect back to root will likely have been cached by the browser (since this is a 301 - permanent - redirect).

Comment: You are a legend! This seems to be working nicely. I just want to test it some more though to make sure and get back to you a bit later. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ah, I just realised that I forgot something. When I try to go to the /quotes/ admin login it redirects me to the root login eg: http://example.com/quotes/wp-admin it goes to https://example.com/wp-admin

Comment: New question regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64605388/prevent-admin-directory-from-redirecting-using-url-rewrite-rules